# Installing a new cursor theme in Lubuntu (LXDE)

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, cursor-theme

I've downloaded a new cursor theme (several .cur or .ani files) but don't know how to install it. I've searched in the previous discussions but they're all about GNOME (they use Gnome Tweak Tool). How can I do it? TY

Comment: In lubuntu, run lxappearance ;)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 :Create a folder /home/your_name/.themes

Step 2: Extract downloaded archive.

Step 3: Move extracted folders to /home/your_name/.themes

I took it from here: [Youtube video about LXDE installing a theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lvBhvPXvog)

Comment: I tried but doesn't appear in the lxappearance. I want to specify that I want to install a CURSOR theme.

Comment: I've been searching around and the problem seems to be that the archive I downloaded does not contain any .theme file, so the system doesn't see it. Does anyone know how to add such a file?